# Strange CSS Footer Bug

Tags: css, html, size, wrapper, footer

Hey I have a Problem with my Footer div on my Homepage

http://kelteseth.net/2012/04/einsteigerhilfe-unterschied-ubuntu-kubuntu-und-xubuntu/

The Problem is that the **wrapper div** dos not have the same height als the **content div**. The footer div is in the center of my Website :/ How can I **change the size** of my **wrapper div** in dependence on the size of my **content div**?

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="content">
<!-- My content... -->
</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
<!-- My footer stuff... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `clear: both;` to your `#footer` style.

The `#content` and `#primary` divs are floated, so they don't influence the height of the `#wrapper` div.

Edit: This method doesn't change the height of the `#wrapper` div, so if you plan to give it a border or a background image, Lars Nyström's `overflow: auto;` method will be better for you.

Answer (score 1):

Set `overflow: auto;` for `#wrapper`

The reason this occurs is because the parent element of a floating element collapses. There are a number of techniques to solve it. The one I mentioned is called the Overflow Method. More info here: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/